# How to retrieve kubernetes cluster data with googleapis in node?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-kubernetes-engine

After researching the topic I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1beta1.projects.locations.clusters) documentation for retiring k8 clusters from GCP. However, I could not find any code examples of utilizing those API's and when I import `google` from `googleapis` I can't find the function in it that would be used for that purpose. For example, to get SQL data there is sqladmin, but nothing for retrieving k8 data. So what property of `google` do I need?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the API?

Comment: Get all gke clusters and information about them on a gcp account (number of nodes, number of deployments, etc). Preferably with googleapis library

Comment: Any other suggestions would be appreciated too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is confusing.

There are 2 distinct APIs that you must use:

1. Google's Kubernetes Engine API (see [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/)). This API is used to create, read, update and delete Kubernetes clusters. Google provides a Node.js SDK documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/container/latest).
2. The standard, generic Kubernetes API (see [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/)). This API is used to create, read, update and delete resources **on** (any) Kubernetes client and, for obvious(ly good) reasons, it is the API that you must use to interact with (an existing) Kubernetes Engine cluster too (because these are just like every other Kubernetes cluster). Kubernetes provides [official and community-supported libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) that implement the Kubernetes API. You'll need to pick one of the [community-supported libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) for Node.js (as there's no official library).

The general process is to:

1. Use the Kubernetes Engine API to e.g. [`projects.locations.cluster.get`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters/get) details of an existing GKE cluster
2. Use the returned [`Cluster`](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters#Cluster) object to build a configuration object (the equivalent of building a `context` object in a kubeconfig file)<sup>go</sup>
3. Use the `context` object with the Kubernetes API library to authenticate to the cluster and program it e.g. list Deployments, create Services etc.

<sup>go</sup>-- I have [code](https://gist.github.com/DazWilkin/9506c0b9677d53a3e11b7457ed21cbe7) for this step but it's written in Golang not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The `kubectl` is the better tool to talk to a Kubernetes cluster.

But, you can retrieve some data from GKE. See below:

```
GCLOUD_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
curl -sS -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GCLOUD_TOKEN}" "https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/some-project-id/locations/us-east4-a/clusters"
```

This way you hit the API REST endpoint authenticated. Because you obtained a token from `gcloud auth print-access-token` on **GCLOUD_TOKEN** variable wherein you'll fill the **Authorization** header.

So you get a JSON reply as desired.

The documentation you linked has more details itself.

Comment: Not really what I am looking for (a node solution utilizing googleapis library), but I'll keep this in mind

Comment: @Newbee Yes, you need to understand the API endpoints from Google API.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).